# How can I make an executable to run different processes?

Tags: server, wine, pdf, process

I am running PDFXCview.exe (for pdfxchange viewer portable version) under wine to open a pdf file, by

```
PDFXCview.exe 1.pdf
```

When I do the same for another file, the other file will be opened by the same process of PDFXCview.exe. Can I open it in a different process? The reason is that the application becomes slower to non-responsive when there are two pdf files opened in the same process.

Is running a different process or not determined by the executable PDFXCview.exe? Is it because the exe file runs as a server?

is the solution the same for other native linux applications?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the following work? `PDFXCview.exe 1.pdf &`, then `PDFXCview.exe 2.pdf &`

Comment: That's application dependent. Firefox and gnome-terminal, for example, have options to disable such behaviour. PDFXCview.exe may or may not have such an option.

Comment: @the_Seppi The two pdf files will be opened in the same process. Putting into background doesn't help. I actually ran it as `nohup pdFXCview.exe 1.pdf &`.

Comment: @muru: what might be the option called? I will try to see if I can find it.

Comment: @Tim it varies. For firefox: `-no-remote`, for gnome-terminal: `--disable-factory`.

Comment: According to [this page](http://help.tracker-software.com/EUM/default.aspx?pageid=PDFXView25:command_line_options), there are a couple of options called `RegServer` and `UnregServer`. They might be useful.

Comment: @muru: adding either of RegServer and UnregServer, will not start the exe. things become worse. My wine is 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't look like a command line way to do it. You have to enable the *Allow Multiple Instances* option:

[image]
After you apply this option, `PDFXCview` should open new windows.